# How can I build some search criteria with 9 fields

Tags: filter, fast-search

I am using SharePoint 2010. I have created a Document Library. In this document library I am using some custom content type with 9 fields. I would like to make some search page where it is possible to enter search criteria in these 9 fields. We are using FAST search. Maybe in javascript/CAML query or something OOTB?

[image: Attached Image]

Comment: Use tools like CAML Designer or SearchQueryTool to test and construct your queyr (either CAML or Search, not sure the tool supports Fast searchn, though)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created ManagedProperties for each of your column than, use simple js to build your query. So let's say user entered Title, DocumentId then build your query like Title:Value Or DocumentId:Value

For All scenarios you can do Title:Value Or DocumentId:Value Or Sort:Value ....

Other approach for All scenario is, create a managed property and include all the columns you want in that. Now for search just use this property e.g. AllCols:Value

Sample js code:

```
var query = "";
function search(){
    query = "";
    var title = $("#title").val(); 
    var DocId= $("#DocId").val(); 
    var ISBNNum = $("#ISBNNum").val(); 
    var Taal = $("#Taal").val(); 
    query="k=";
    if(title!=""){
        query+="Title:"+title;
    }
    if(DocId!=""){
        query+=" OR DocId:"+DocId;
    }
    if(ISBNNum!=""){
        query+= " OR ISBN:"+ISBNNum;
    }
    if(Taal!=""){
        query+= " OR Taal:"+Taal;
    }    
    location.href="<search results page url>"+"?"+query;    
}
```

This is really crude code. You will need to improve it as how you have your html.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this query? Can I find somewhere an example of searching with a query in js in sp2010 and FAST search?

Comment: you just need to build your query using js, and then just pass that as parameter to your search results page. i have updated the answer for sample js code. you will to have improve it as per your need, but that is the basic idea.